# That shade of green isn’t really workin’ for you

Tags: expressions, american-english

So I'm reading a book, there's some humour on a page where there's an 'Advice guy' that says things.
Here's three of the things he says:

1)"Treat yourself to
a cold one! You
deserve it!"

That I know refers to beer

2)"Tell your boss
the report will
have to wait. There’s
powder at Aspen!"

I found the meaning of that [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268157/theres-a-powder-at-aspen-expression-means-what)

3)"That shade of
green isn’t really
workin’ for you..."

I don't quite get the third one, what's the play on words here?

Edit:
So I did add some context in a comment below but I'm editing this so you have it here as well.

Well, this is from a book on programming using Java(Head First Java). But this particular part is just there to add in some humour. The authors are known to make a lot of remarks which don't necessarily have to do anything with programming directly. The context here is that the advice guy gives you advice when you're having those 'long days of coding' (and possibly need someone to cheer you up, I suppose). These things are usually references to something from the real world or rather just a play on words. Like the second quote, powder on Aspen. That's to say there's fresh snow at the Aspen ski resort thereby hinting at you taking a break and going skiing there. So really, it's either a reference you get, or you don't.. there isn't so much as to the context. That's how the authors wrote the book(The humorous parts I mean, some-people-get-the-joke-some-don't-kind). In this case, I could get the meaning of the first two quotes but couldn't guess at the third one. 
 Looking at the answers below, it does seem like just a remark at clothing, but I asked for confirmation/possible variation.

Comment: Can you provide more context? It could be referring to envy: "green with envy" is an idiom used to describe people who seem envious, but without context I wouldn't be confident posting that as an answer.

Comment: Well, this is from a book on programming using Java(Head First Java). But this particular part is just there to add in some humour. The authors are known to make a lot of remarks which don't necessarily have to do anything with programming directly. The context here is that the advice guy gives you advice when you're having those 'long days of coding' (and possibly need someone to cheer you up, I suppose). Does that help?

Comment: Could it refer to a colour you are wearing that doesn't suit you? "Go out and buy some new clothes."

Comment: well, in general yes, but I'm not sure if that's really contextual here

Comment: What would it take to convince you that it is contextual? (Although I'm not sure that the suggestion to buy new clothes is supported - more that it seems to be a euphemism for "That the shade looks awful on you.") I suggest you enter "isn't working for you" (including quotes) into a search engine.  "X works for me" = "In my case, X is a successful strategy."

Comment: I've seen a few examples on the internet where 'That shade of green isn’t really workin’ for you' / 'That shade of green doesn't really suit you' is, as @nnnnnn suggests, a nicely euphemistic way of saying 'Don't be jealous!' But there are too few for this to be idiomatic. I'd consider using it in contexts where the meaning is clear, and it's a nice metaphor, so will probably catch on. But non-idiomatic (and so off-topic here) at the moment. // Also, there is next to no context at the original posting, so this is open to opinion.

Comment: @Ayush Please provide the context to the third quote. That will answer any doubts about whether or not it's relevant. If it is (and I think it probably *is* relevant, as the comments and answers so far attest) then it will help people give reasoned answers. At the moment, there isn't enough information here. You can flag the question for re-opening when it's complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absent context it's difficult to guess at the intended meaning.  Literally, it would mean that you have on an article of clothing which is green in color and that particular shade of green is unflattering.

Slightly less literally, it could suggest that you appear to be "green with envy" (a common idiom), and that the envy is not flattering to you.

More figuratively, it could imply that you are simply being stupid.

Answer (score 0):

The third sentence is arbitrary in nature, and can be applied to a myriad of situations. However, by definition, it would imply that something is not working for you and it's visible to others. Thus, the colour reference. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello, nathansaurus. Please look in the Help Center to discover the type of answers desired (and expected) on ELU, and in fact on any StackExchange site. Speculative answers are hardly ever appropriate. Speculations that might help _may_ be offered in 'comments'. And we've all had to build up enough rep points to gain that privilege.